# SolrNet Traditional Mapping with Result Grouping and Highlighting

Tags: c#, solr, grouping, highlighting, solrnet

SolrNet Result grouping and highlighting in QueryOptions not retrieving any result.I think my problem could be the Traditional mapping that I'm using.
below is
Core added as:

```
windsorSolrStartUp.AddCore(suggestionsIndex.IndexName,typeof(SuggestionsIndexMapper), ConfigurationSettings.ContentSearch_Solr_ServiceBaseAddress + "/" + suggestionsIndex.IndexName);
```

SuggestionsIndexMapper.cs

```
  public class SuggestionsIndexMapper: ISuggestionsIndexMapper
  {
    public SuggestionsIndexMapper()
    {
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Composite ID: contains SuggestionType,SitecoreItemID,Site,Language
    /// Created on fly during indexing in solr. 
    /// Checkout schema.xml and solrconfig.xml
    /// </summary>
    [SolrUniqueKey("compositeId")]
    public string CompositeId { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// SitecoreId
    /// </summary>
    [SolrField("sitecoreId")]
    public string SitecoreId { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// DisplayName
    /// </summary>
    [SolrField("name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Imageurl
    /// </summary>
    [SolrField("imageUrl")]
    public string ImageUrl { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Url
    /// </summary>
    [SolrField("url")]
    public string Url { get; set; }
  }
```

SolrSearchContext looks as follows:

```
 public class SolrSearchContext<T> : ISolrSearchContext<T>
{
    public readonly ISolrOperations<T> IndexOperations;

    public SolrSearchContext() {}

    /// <summary>
    /// Setting the indexOperations for given index
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="indexName"></param>
    public SolrSearchContext(string indexName)
    {
        IOC ioc = new IOC();
        IndexOperations = ioc.GetContainer().Resolve<ISolrOperations<T>>(indexName);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Get IndexOperations for index
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public ISolrOperations<T> GetIndexOperations()
    {
        return IndexOperations;
    }
public SolrQueryResults<T> ExecuteQuery(ISolrQuery query, QueryOptions queryOptions = null)
    {
        try
        {
            Logger.Debug(string.Format("SolrSearchContext - ExecuteQuery: Executing your query {0}", query));
            if (queryOptions != null)
            {
                return IndexOperations.Query(query, queryOptions);
            }
            return IndexOperations.Query(query);
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            Logger.Debug(string.Format("SolrSearchContext - ExecuteQuery: Error while executing the query - {0} is {1}", query, e));
            return new SolrQueryResults<T>();
        }
    }
}
```

Index is:

```
public class SuggestionsIndex: SearchIndex<SuggestionsIndexMapper>
{
    public override string IndexName
    {
        get { return "suggestions_index"; }
    }

    public override string SwapIndexName
    {
        get { return "suggestions_index_swap"; }
    }
}

public class SearchIndex<T> : ISearchIndex<T>
{
    public ISolrSearchContext<T> CreateSearchContext()
    {
        return new SolrSearchContext<T>(IndexName);
    }

    public virtual string IndexName { get; set; }
    public virtual string SwapIndexName { get; set; }
}
```

So for each index we have the SolrSearchContext intialized with its Mapping Class in this case SuggestionsIndexMapper.

Now when querying the Solr,

```
  ISolrQuery query = QueryBuilder(site, language, term);
        QueryOptions queryOptions = new QueryOptions()
        {
            Highlight = new HighlightingParameters()
            {
                Fields = new[] {"uvw"} 
            },
            Grouping = new GroupingParameters()
            {
                Fields = new[] { "xyz"},
                Format = GroupingFormat.Grouped,
                Limit = 3
            }
        };
  SuggestionsIndex index = new SuggestionsIndex();
  ISolrSearchContext<SuggestionsIndexMapper> searchContext = index.CreateSearchContext();
  var results = searchContext.ExecuteQuery(query, queryOptions).ToList();
```

The results come as empty.If I do not use Result grouping or highlighting they get mapped correctly to the results variable of type List of SuggestionsIndexMapper.

How should I map the data, so can access the various groups in solr result and also the higlighting results?

Any help will be greatful.
Thanks,

Comment: I was to access the Result Groupings and the highlights by not doing .toList() for the result from executeQuery. This gives the entire result from solr. With grouping and highlights. And can be accessed as results.Grouping and results.Highlights

Answer (score 0):

I was able to access the Result Groupings and the highlights by not doing .toList() for the result from executeQuery.
Instead of:
     var results = searchContext.ExecuteQuery(query, queryOptions).ToList();
Basically just do: 
     var results = searchContext.ExecuteQuery(query, queryOptions);
     Var highlights = results.higlights;
     var grouping = results.grouping;

This gives the entire result from solr. With grouping and highlights.